# pandas split based on sep=' ' not working

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a text file that I'm working with and it's separated by a spaces instead of commas.  I have done a few of these always creating a one long row and then splitting to columns where needed. The data has always lined up until now and I have hit a snag. Below I have a dataframe of some example text.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Start at (0,Test) in the series. Work down.
2. Check element at (0,Test) for number or letter at first position (0) of
   string.
   If number exist, skip or do nothing.
   If letter exist, code needed to split at the first whitespace occurrence:
   `df[['First Name', 'Test']] = df['Test'].str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)` and
   remove the first name from the Test column and place it in the First Name column.
3. Move to the next row down and repeat until done with series.
4. (Bonus): A middle initial could follow the first name (line 1). If possible
   could this be captured as well?

code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

list = {'Test': ['9/21/2019 1 9/29/2019',
                 'Cynthia T. CC 9/21/2016 1 9/30/2019',
                 '9/12/2019 1 9/12/2012',
                 'Hannah A/R 9/20/2015 1 9/07/2016',
                 'John CC 9/26/2019 3 9/29/2019']}

df = pd.DataFrame(list)

# for n in df.Test:
#     if n[0].isalpha:
#         df[['First Name', 'Test']] = df['Test'].str.split(" ", 1, 
           expand=True)
#     else:
#         continue

print(df)

#----------------------------
# Currently:
#    Test
# 0  9/21/2019 1 9/29/2019
# 1  Cynthia T. CC 9/21/2016 1 9/30/2019
# 2  9/12/2019 1 9/12/2012
# 3  Hannah A/R 9/20/2015 1 9/07/2016
# 4  John CC 9/26/2019 3 9/29/2019

# What I would like:
#    Test                                                 First Name
# 0  9/21/2019 1 9/29/2019                                NaN
# 1  CC 9/21/2016 1 9/30/2019                             Cynthia T.
# 2  9/12/2019 1 9/12/2012                                NaN
# 3  A/R 9/20/2015 1 9/07/2016                            Hannah
# 4  CC 9/26/2019 3 9/29/2019                             John
```

As always, your time and knowledge is appreciated. I thank you for any assistance.

Comment: if you provide a (non-truncated) example of the text in your file we can help

Comment: also, please make the question more concise :). We just need the input and expected output

Comment: Anon01, the dataframe above is the example that I'm working with. Also, pasted at the botton of the code REM'd out is currently what is displaying as well as what I would like to display.  As far as the question goes. is there a way to cycle down thru a series if string[0] isalpha then perform a .str.split(" ", 1, expand=True) and remove the first name  and place it in a new column.  Like the example above. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want.  I'll take a look if you can make the question more concise

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks Anon01, I have edited the info. please take a look when you  have time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the split (and also check for alpha) with pandas string accessors.

```
# split and get the first name
df['First Name'] = df['Test'].str.split(n=1).str[0]

# filter out numerics
df['First Name'] = df['First Name'].where(df['First Name'].str.isalpha())
```

Output

```
                                  Test First Name
0                9/21/2019 1 9/29/2019        NaN
1  Cynthia T. CC 9/21/2016 1 9/30/2019    Cynthia
2                9/12/2019 1 9/12/2012        NaN
3     Hannah A/R 9/20/2015 1 9/07/2016     Hannah
4        John CC 9/26/2019 3 9/29/2019       John
```

Comment: Hello RichieV, Thanks for looking into this. One thing, shouldn't the split method remove the first name (in this case) from the ['Test'] column? Could this be worked into your code?

Comment: It's almost what I need, the only other question I might have is looking at step 4. Some of the strings contain a middle initial with a period. Example Above Line 1: Cynthia T.  Could your code be worked to catch these type strings?

Comment: Yes, keep all to the right side of the occurrence.  I have a long line of code that I'm plucking off one occurrence at a time and placing into a new column....Hope this make sense.

Comment: Have `First name` be `Cynthia T.` and keep `Test` as `CC 9/21/2016...` ?

Comment: Yes...that looks good. Some middle initials have a period after the initial and some don't.  If the period is left behind I can do a lstrip on the period to remove I think.

Comment: Question: do all the rows have the same number of dates? all with an integer in between the dates? I might be easier to split from the right, one at a time

Comment: This is one long string and very uneven string.  The left side of string is more stable.  Could we chat? maybe I can explain

Comment: Just edit your question and append a section explaining this, I'll take a look at it if you leave another comment when you're done. This way maybe somebody else will fix it in case I get busy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220985/discussion-between-boomer-and-richiev).